# Why does a list initialised with Nil and cons (::) not have a NULL value at the end?

Tags: scala

Today is my first day of learning Scala, and one of the things I have learnt is that a common way to initialise lists combines Nil (an empty list) with :: (prepend method).

Let's say I initialise a list this way:

```
val myList = List("A", "B", "C")
```

which is the same as:

```
val myList = "A" :: "B" :: "C" :: Nil
```

I understand that you can read the second chunk as the following:

1. Start with an empty list
2. Add "C" to the beginning of that list. The list is no longer empty.
3. Add "B" to the beginning of the list.
4. Add "A" to the beginning of the list.
5. Assign the list to the immutable List collection. The data type of each list element is inferred (String).

What I don't understand is *why doesn't Nil act the same as NULL? Why is there no NULL value at the end of the list when it is initialised in this way?*

(Forgive me, OOP and FP are not my thing but I'd like to learn.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to call methods on all lists including empty list (for example `Nil.length`), `Nil` must be an object, not `null`. Otherwise you'll have `NullPointerException` instead of `0`.

Also it's necessary for type safety. `Nil` is a value of type `List[Nothing]`, i.e. of `List[A]` for all `A` (because `List` is covariant). And `null` is a value of type `Null` i.e. of all reference types (because `Null` is a subtype of any reference type), not only of list types.

Answer (score 1):

Too many things to learn. You first need to understand what is an object, what is a class, what is an interface / trait, what is a value, what is a type. Then with those, you may need to learn about **ADTs**.

I will try to give a quick answer to that.

The `List` datatype is defined as

```
sealed trait List[+A]
final case class ::[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
final case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

So here we can see three things: a **trait**, a **class** and an **object**.

- A **class** is a blueprint of memory for creating objects *(also called instances)*. It is not a value, for using it you have to call its constructor *(in this case, it receives two values, the `head` and the `tail`)* to get a new value of that class.
- An **object** is like an anonymous class that is already instantiated, so it is already a value, which you can use as it is.
- A **trait** is a like a class that can not be instantiated, it is said to be abstract. It is used to define common behaviors that all subclasses have to follow.

Also, when the trait is sealed and the classes and objects are `cases`, we call those **ADTs** *(algebraic data types)*.
Do not let the fancy name to scare you, it just means that the trait represents a single type *(om this case the List)* and all the cases represents the parts of such type.
ADTs are formed of products and sums, sums represents alternatives *(it is an A or a B)* and products represents conjunctions *(it is an A and a B)*.
In the case of the **List** we say that it is either the empty list *(`Nil`)* or a cons *(`::`)* which has its own head and tail, where the tail is another list.

With all that, and a the knowledge that Scala has a syntactic trick to allow symbolic names to be used in the middle, you can see that this:

```
val list = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
```

Is the same as:

```
val list = new ::(
  head = 1,
  tail = new ::(
    head = 2,
    tail = new ::(
      head = 3,
      tail = Nil
    )
  )
)
```

---

Bonus:

- [There are more types than classes](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html).
- `null` its a value of type **Null** *(the only value to habit such type)*, which is a subtype of all the **AnyRef** types. It is, however, a special kind of value; because it will fail if you try to operate with it in any way. My advice, forget that it exists, it was a mistake and it is only there for **Java** interop. If you need to model the absence of a value use `Option`.